# how to get index position of a droppable div in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using drag and drop functionality.
I want index position of a div which is dropped something like 1 ,2,3...after each drop.

I used .position() and .offset() method but it gives me top and left index position in px
 my code is

```
$(".workArea").droppable({
drop: function( event, ui ) {
var y = ui.position.left();
var z = ui.position.top();
```

Please help in getting index position like 1,2 ,3 after each drop

Comment: What do you mean by "index position"?

Comment: `$(event.target).index() `

Comment: @dean: means after drop it should give me position number  i.e. 1 for 1st drop 2 for 2nd drop and so on

Comment: Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
 drop: function(event, ui) {

        alert($(event.target).index());

    }
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Fep8h/

Comment: `event.target` is not a jQuery object !

Comment: @Dean: draggable.index always giving me 0 for first div dropped as in my example i drop heading div twice and it gives me index 0 for both

Answer (score 0):

check this :)

```
 var postionA = value1;
 var postionB = value2;
$("#div").droppable({
   drop: function( event, resp ) {
      console.log(resp.positionA,resp.positionB,resp.target);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below gives the index value every time 5.

```
drop: function(event, ui) {
   alert($(event.target).index());
}
```

my code is following

```
$("#sortable").droppable({
       helper: "clone",
       drop: function (event, ui) {
          alert($(ui.placeholder).index());
       }
 });
```